# Public libre collaborative calendar

Tags: open-source, web-apps, calendar

I am part of a group of parents organising a rota for a "pedibus" walking ten to twenty children to school. We are currently using a Google spreadsheet that everyone can access and modify to sign up for their day. However, it would be nice if we could see in our calendar apps the name of the person who is responsible tomorrow and the day after and so on, and not have to connect to the spreadsheet, or fill the rota out even.

I would therefore like to find an online calendar service or program with as many of the following characteristics as possible:

- Free as in freedom
- Publicly modifiable without a login
- HTML web interface
- Readable with calendar clients like Apple Calendar or Google Calendar
- Modifiable with calendar clients

Does such a thing exist or is it technically impossible?

Google Calendar requires you to have an account and is not free/libre.
Framagenda.org ticks all the boxes but requires users to have a login in order to modify the calendar. I don't mind putting something on my server but I'd rather avoid this. I found these ideas: https://www.linux.com/learn/five-best-open-source-calendar-servers-linux. [Radicale](https://radicale.org/) looks promising; has anyone tried it?

Comment: I'm not using it myself, but heard from people on a similar hunt it should match pretty well. If all you need is just a calendar, things like Nextcloud would be a bit overkill. Radicale would be something coming to my mind first, next to Baïkal (which I didn't try either; I'm using Nextcloud as I also need some additional features it provides which Baïcal/Radicale don't offer).